# chart.DrawToBitmap blank

Tags: c#

I have some code that uses System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting; to generate a chart and create a bitmap image

```
private Bitmap GetTargetGradingImage(int sessionsTrained, int target, int height, int width)
        {
            const string TargetSeries = "TargetSeries";
            var chart = new Chart
            {
                Height = height,
                Width = width
            };
            chart.ChartAreas.Add(new ChartArea()
            {
                Name = "ChartArea1"
            });
            chart.Series.Clear();
            chart.Series.Add(new Series()
            {
                Name = TargetSeries,
                IsVisibleInLegend = true,
                ChartType = SeriesChartType.Column,
                Color = Color.Green
            });
            chart.Series[TargetSeries].ChartArea = chart.ChartAreas[0].Name;
            string[] XPointMember = new string[2];
            int[] YPointMember = new int[2];
            XPointMember[0] = "Sessions";
            YPointMember[0] = sessionsTrained;
            XPointMember[1] = "Target";
            YPointMember[1] = target;
            chart.Series[TargetSeries].Points.DataBindXY(XPointMember, YPointMember);
            chart.Invalidate();
            var bitmap = new Bitmap(chart.Size.Width, chart.Size.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
            chart.DrawToBitmap(bitmap, chart.Bounds);
            //chart.DrawToBitmap(bitmap, new Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Size.Width, bitmap.Size.Height));
            return bitmap;
        }
```

This works fine on my dev system but not when published to an Azure website. The images are blank.
The images are being used for inclusion in html emails.
Any ideas?

Comment: Are the white, chartarea backcolor or black? Or are just points missing?  What do you mean it 'work on dev. sys'? your data look all 0s..

Answer (score 1):

Cracked it.

Didn't need the chart.DrawToBitmap bit at all

This works

```
using (var chartImage = new MemoryStream())
            {
                chart.SaveImage(chartImage, ChartImageFormat.Png);
                targetBuf = Convert.ToBase64String(chartImage.ToArray());
            }
```

This gives me a Base64 encoded string that I can use in an img tag